# reeling in flight; meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of *reeling in flight*?

> He has destroyed host and sent the lords of Trident ***reeling in flight***.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's *staggering* but I'm not sure.

Comment: Reel, in, and flight are all in the dictionary. Which word gives you trouble? What definitions have you found and why have they not made sense? Which dictionaries have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Reel**
>
> *Verb*
>
> 2.lose one's balance and stagger or lurch violently

They were so eager to get away that they lost their footing. The imagery is of individuals being trampled upon in a general "everyone for himself" rush to escape.